# Displaying error message for specific conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to display a specific error/warning message when a specific conditions is met. To be specific,

1) Unregistered or invalid user will get the $errMsg2 error message(I have this done)

2) Registered and 'notvoted' user will login successfully and proceed with the voting flow(I have this done)

3) Registed and 'voted' user should have something like "You have voted!" error message. Instead it kept on displaying the $errMsg2 error(Which is my main issue here).

*I have declared $stat and $stat2 respectively as it matches my mySQL db variables/structure.

I have tried playing around a lot with the if/else statement but I can't get the $stat2 conditions to meet.

Please help.

Below is my php code,

```
$stat='notvoted';
$stat2='voted';

//Create query
if($position=='Admin') {
$qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
}
if($position=='Student') {
$qry="SELECT * FROM students WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password' AND status='$stat'";
}
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        if($position=='Student') {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] = $member['course'];
        $_SESSION['NAME'] = $member['name'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: candidates_list.php");
        exit();
        }
        if($position=='Admin') {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: admin/index.php");
        exit();
        }
        }else if($stat2==TRUE){
     header("location: index.php");
        $_SESSION['errMsg3'] = "You have voted!";
        exit();
       }else{
        header("location: index.php");
        $_SESSION['errMsg2'] = "Invalid username or password, please re-             
        enter or register first";
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using $stat2

Comment: @MateoBarahona yes i removed it because I have been experimenting everywhere and still havent got the solution. So if someone could advise me on how to implement it that would be great.

Comment: This code will assume that the password is posted, even if there is already a session. Is this really what you want? I would think that once the user has sent the password, their next move should not involve a password any more, and if you then still check for a password match, it will fail.

Comment: You should just get the user from Db and then check if his status is $stat1 (case 1) or $stat2 (case 2). You can also restrict in the Query by using status IN ($stat1,$stat2)

Comment: You're also checking if 'Student' twice.  If it fails the first time, you will go straight to die.

Comment: @trincot I have updated the question to include the full code.

Comment: @MateoBarahona I can't really imagine the code structure yet, can you give some example on the usage for the case1/case2 and IN query?

Comment: @MikeWu i have updated the code, please advise. previously i just took a bit of it so its probably doenst make much sense.

Comment: Why are you testing $stat2 == TRUE ? You set the variable to "voted"

Comment: Where and how is $position defined? Shouldn't this info come from the database and retrieved from the query you issue?

Comment: @MateoBarahona i am kinda lost to be honest. what should I test it with then? I did put 'voted' in there but that'd be redundant.

Comment: @trincot it is defined a bit above from where I defined $stat and $stat2, and called from <select> in index.php(log in page). It is also will be triggered once the "LOG IN" button is clicked.

Comment: Well that seems wrong: a student could pretend to be administrator then, no?

Comment: Hi Luqman....the code posted has $stat2 = 'voted' at the top but it is never used until the if statement.  It is always set to 'voted'.  The if then checks if( stat2 == TRUE ) which says 'voted' == TRUE, which I don't think is what you want.  Should $stat2 ever change and if so should it be set to 'voted'?

Comment: @thehappymamba hello, there's only 2 states will present in the field "status" inside my DB, which is 'voted' and 'notvoted'. My primary intention is to have any student with 'notvoted' status will be successfully logged in, which student with 'voted' status will be denied login and instead will be displayed an error message saying "you have voted". hope its clearer.

Comment: @trincot i have set some validations, and they are working fine. but thats not the issue here i think. I just want those with the 'voted' status student to have different error msg than those who havent registered.

Comment: Ah ok.  In the code, I don't see where status from the database is being used.  Has the code been updated to use that value instead of the hard coded values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the voting status from the database and compare it with 'voted'.

Here is some code you might be looking for:

```
//Create query
$qry = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
$result or die("Query failed");

// Check for wrong credentials
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    header("location: index.php");
    $_SESSION['errMsg2'] = "Invalid username or password, please             
                            re-enter or register first";
    exit();
}

// Login successful, fetch properties
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($position == 'Student') {
    // Check voting status
    if ($member['status'] == 'voted') {
        header("location: index.php");
        $_SESSION['errMsg3'] = "You have voted!";
        exit();
    }
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] = $member['course'];
    $_SESSION['NAME'] = $member['name'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: candidates_list.php");
    exit();
}
if ($position == 'Admin') {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: admin/index.php");
    exit();
}
```

There are however several issues remaining:

- It is not clear how `$position` got it's value. Ideally the `students` table should
  have this information (or a reference to it), and you should check that the connecting
  user is not trying to take the administrator role without having the right to do so.
  It is not enough to have some limitations on the client (`HTML`) side, for making 
  sure this does not happen. You must check again in the database that it is OK for 
  the user to act as administrator.
- `$login` and `$password` should first be checked not to contain anything that would
  turn the `SELECT` statement into something revealing unwanted information or 
  having side-effects (read about [`SQL` injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ). One important 
  improvement would be to not allow the presence of a single quote in
  either `$login` or `$password`.
- The code uses deprecated `mysql_` functions. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` 
  extension should be used.
- Less important: it is strange to see `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` being set
  with a different field's value depending on the position.  It seems more logical to build your
  code in such a way that it always corresponds to same field: either `username`
  or `id`, the session variable name suggesting it should be the second.